# Access added (sub) control in VB .NET

Tags: vb.net

With this code I dynamicly add a panel with two panels inside (a header and a data panel). Within the Data panel there is also a label that I like to access.

Now I like to access the label inside the data panel but can't reach it with:

```
test_label.text = "this a second test"
```

Here the dynamicaly added panels

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim newPanelMain As Panel = New Panel With {
            .Location = New Point(200, 500),
            .Name = "test",
            .Size = New Size(500, 500)
        }

        Dim newPanelHeader As Panel = New Panel With {
            .Name = newPanelMain.Name & "_header",
            .BackColor = Color.Orange,
            .Dock = DockStyle.Top,
            .Height = 50
        }
        newPanelMain.Controls.Add(newPanelHeader)

        Dim newPanelData As Panel = New Panel With {
            .Name = newPanelMain.Name & "_data",
            .Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
            .BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
        }
        newPanelMain.Controls.Add(newPanelData)

        Dim newPanelSize As Panel = New Panel With {
            .Name = newPanelMain.Name & (("_size")),
            .BackColor = Color.Red,
            .Height = 20,
            .Width = 20,
            .Location = New Point(newPanelData.Width - 20, newPanelData.Height - 20)
        }
        newPanelData.Controls.Add(newPanelSize)

        Dim newLabel As Label = New Label With {
            .Text = "This is a test",
            .Name = newPanelMain.Name & (("_label")),
            .Location = New Point(0, 0),
            .AutoSize = True
        }
        newPanelData.Controls.Add(newLabel)


        Me.Controls.Add(newPanelMain)
 
    End Sub
```

Comment: It's silly to create all those controls at run time. Look into [user controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.usercontrol?view=netframework-4.8) and then you just have to create one control and add it.

Comment: You add a user control to your project in the same way as you add a form. You then design it and add code just like a form to. Once you build, you can then use it just like any other control. To access a property of a child control, you should declare a property in the user control that passes data into and out of that child control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare `newLabel` as a [member variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/variables/variable-declaration):

```
Private newLabel As Label
```

So you can use this code:

```
Me.newLabel = New Label With {
    .Text = "This is a test",
    .Name = newPanelMain.Name & (("_label")),
    .Location = New Point(0, newPanelHeader.Height + 10),
    .AutoSize = True
}
newPanelData.Controls.Add(Me.newLabel)
```

And then change its `.Text` property using:

```
Me.newLabel.Text = "this a second test"
```

In a different situation (e.g. if you have multiple `Labels` created at runtime) remember that you can use `Control.ControlCollection` class:

```
CType(CType(Me.Controls("test"), Panel).Controls("test_data"), Panel).Controls("test_label").Text = "this is a third test"
```

Comment: There's no need for either of those `CType` calls in that last snippet because you already get a `Control` reference and `Controls` is a member of that type.